# how to create a mysql event to affect another table

Tags: mysql, events, mariadb

Sorry if this is a pretty simple question, I've never wrote an event before in a mysql table and need some help. I have two tables that are related to each other.
Table 1 that will never be truncated or deleted, it will have a column that has is_checked with a 0/1. Table 2 will be a similar table but will only include records that haven't been checked yet and also include a column that has is_checked. This is what I want to happen. I have someone looking through table 2 at each record and once they check the record they will be able to record they have checked it, then the master table will update its record and the smaller table will have that record deleted. For example:

Table 2
is_checked 0 --> 1 then
Table1
is_checked 0 --> 1
Table 2
record is dropped.

> CREATE TRIGGER before_t1_update
> AFTER UPDATE ON t1
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
> IF is_updated = 1 then
> UPDATE t2
> set is_updated = 1 where sdn_id = id;

This is what I tried so far, but like I said I'm a rookie at this :D

Comment: What you are talking about is a trigger and you can action table1 through a trigger fired by an action on table2 but you cannot delete (not drop) a row in table2 in a trigger fired by table2. I'm not seeing the purpose of table2 at all or what you mean by 'they will be able to record they have checked it,' - you could have a trigger on table2 which logs the change.

Comment: yeah now that I'm thinking about it all probably could be done in table 1. they check the record once they check it, then the is_checked changes to 1. Table 2 may be redundant.